# Calculating two numbers

Tags: math, numbers

Sorry for asking this question, I didn't pay attention in school...

Say I have two numbers: 3 and 7

I'd like to create a bar that shows the percentage of both numbers (out of 100%)
in other words, calculate those numbers, so the bar shows:
IIIXXXXXXX

I hope I make sense.. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean you want a bar to display 3 and 7 as relative values, each taking up an appropriate percentage of the whole

> IIIXXXXXXX

The calculation is simple:

```
var total = 3 + 7;
var percentA = 3 / total; // 30%
var percentB = 7 / total; // 70%
```

The width of each component is the total bar width multiplied by the selected value and divided by the sum of values.

So if the bar should be, say, 100px, you would calculate the width of the two components like

```
var widthA = 100 * ( A / (A+B) );
var widthB = 100 * ( B / (A+B) );
```

or `100 * ( 3 / (3+7) ) => 100 * (3/10) => 30`, and 70.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way (taken from a progress bar plugin):

This is JavaScript, but the language is of course irrelevant.

```
var max = 250; // the total amount representing 100%
var current = $obj.val().length; // the length we are measuring

// important: current / max * 100

// use min() to ensure that the result isn't greater than 100 due to rounding
var ratio = Math.min( ( ( current / max ) * 100 ), 100 );
```

The key piece is dividing the current amount by the total amount, where the total amount (whatever it may be) represents 100%. That division operation should yield a value less than 1. To convert that to a 1-100 percentage, multiply by 100.

In my above example, if `current` = 125, and `max` = 250, then we have 125 / 250 = 0.5. Multiplying 0.5 * 100 gives 50. 125 is 50% of 250.

If you wanted to get both percentages, you could simply subtract the first result from 100.

Here is a complete working example of a HTML/CSS/jQuery progress bar for managing the maxlength of a textbox: http://jsfiddle.net/QfZPt/1/

Answer (score 0):

If your asking for a physical representation of the numbers percentage out of 100 I would start by getting the percent:

```
int number = 3; //or 7
int percent = number/100;
```

Then I would have a sprite 1 pixel big and scale it based on `percent`, for example:

```
mybarsprite.scale = percent*100;
```

Then you could add a background image to create the bar and have that be 100 pixels. Add both sprites at the same position, the background sprite at a lower z level add you have a bar affect.